# How do I get the JMS Header JMSMessageID from my message?

Tags: c#-4.0, hornetq, apache-nms

I want to substract the JMSMessageID Header from my message using apache nms. With the message.Properties[] I can only access my message Properties, how do I get the JMSMessageID?

I tried the code below with no success.

ITextMessage message = (ITextMessage)consumer.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
string JMSMessageID = message.Properties["JMSMessageID"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

The Message ID in NMS is accessed via the NMSMessageID properties or I think you can use the "NMSMessageID" string in the Message properties and it will be intercepted and the message ID value will be returned.